# Converting specific letters to uppercase or lowercase in python

Tags: python, string, helper

So to return a copy of a string converted to lowercase or uppercase one obviously uses the `lower()` or `upper()`.

But how does one go about making a copy of a string with *specific* letters converted to upper or lowercase.
For example how would i convert `'test'` into `'TesT'`

this is honestly baffling me so help is greatly appreciated

got it, thanks for the help Cyber and Matt!

Comment: Can you clarify that what you mean by **specific l**? because based on your definition it can have a lot of answer!!!

Comment: If one of the answers helped solve your problem, consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the check mark next to it. It marks your question as resolved to your current satisfaction, and awards [reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking to replace specific letters:

```
>>> s = "test"
>>> s.replace("t", "T")
'TesT'
```

Comment: And here I am always using regexs to replace letters.  Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 4):

There is one obvious solution, slice the string and upper the parts you want:

```
test = 'test'
test = test[0].upper() + test[1:-1] + test[-1].upper()
```

Comment: only if you already know the positions of the letters to change. This is not robust for arbitrary strings...

Comment: but...there must be some way to do it without slicing

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
input = 'test'
change_to_upper = 't'
input = re.sub(change_to_upper, change_to_upper.upper(), input)
```

This uses the regular expression engine to say find anything that matches `change_to_upper` and replace it with the the upper case version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method:

```
import string

# Letters that should be upper-cased
letters = "tzqryp"
table = string.maketrans(letters, letters.upper())


word = "test"
print word.translate(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general way to replace all of a letter with something else

```
>>> swaps = {'t':'T', 'd':'D'}
>>> ''.join(swaps.get(i,i) for i in 'dictionary')
'DicTionary'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use translate().

For python2:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> "test".translate(maketrans("bfty", "BFTY"))
'TesT'
```

And for python3:

```
>>> "test".translate(str.maketrans("bfty", "BFTY"))
'TesT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 can do:

```
def myfunc(str):
  if len(str)>3:
    return str[:3].capitalize() + str[3:].capitalize()
  else:
    return 'Word is too short!!'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
>>> letters = "abcdefghijklmnop"
>>> trantab = str.maketrans(letters, letters.upper())
>>> print("test string".translate(trantab))
tEst strING
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
chars_to_lower = "MTW"
"".join([char.lower() if char in chars_to_lower else char for char in item]
```